# Do jQuery plugin select2's data-* attributes play nice with Backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jquery-select2, custom-data-attribute

Here's a snippet from my template (Backbone with Marionette):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="some_id" class="align-left col-sm-4 control-label">Some Label</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <select id="some_id" style="width:150px;" data-minimumresultsforsearch="10" />
    </div>
</div>
```

then in the onShow method for the View that uses the template:

```
types = ['Type 1', 'Type 2'];
this.$("#some_id").select2({
  data: types
});
```

This is select2 v4.0. The types appear, but the minimumresultsforsearch doesn't have any effect. I'm not sure how to debug it.

FYI, the reason I'm trying to put some configuration in the HTML is that as far as I can tell, I have to use the same configuration options in the onShow and then again in any methods where that element needs to be updated, so I'm repeating a lot of code. If I could put those in the HTML I think I'd only have to use the relevant options, namely 'data:', in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `data-` attribute like this:

`data-minimum-results-for-search="25"`

This will get loaded in to `.data()` as `.data( "minimumResultsForSearch" )` and will be picked up by `select2`. Please have a look at  jQuery's [parsing rules](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) for the same.

```js
$("#myselectbox").select2();
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="myselectbox" data-minimum-results-for-search="25">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>14</option>
<option>15</option>
<option>26</option>
<option>37</option>
<option>38</option>
<option>19</option>
<option>22</option>
<option>222</option>
<option>22</option>
<option>1222</option>
</select>
```